# How to improve LSTM model

Tags: lstm

I have built a LSTM example,but its effect is poor.I don't know how to improve it.
I would be very grateful if you could help me.

**import package**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**set data**

```
np.random.seed(0)
torch.manual_seed(0)

time_steps = np.linspace(0,15,10000);

print("time_steps:");
print(time_steps);

data =np.sin(time_steps)

plt.plot(data, label="Ground Truth")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yisK.png)

**divide the data set and test set**

```
train_len=(int)(len(data)*0.5);

train_data=data[:train_len];
train_data=torch.tensor(train_data).to(torch.float32);

test_data=data[train_len:];
test_data=torch.tensor(test_data).to(torch.float32);

print(train_data);
```

**build LSTM model**

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size,output_size):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()

        self.input_size=input_size;
        self.hidden_size=hidden_size;
        self.output_size=output_size;

        self.Wfh,self.Wfx,self.bf=self.init_Weight_bias_gate();
        self.Wih,self.Wix,self.bi=self.init_Weight_bias_gate();
        self.Woh,self.Wox,self.bo=self.init_Weight_bias_gate();
        self.Wch,self.Wcx,self.bc=self.init_Weight_bias_gate();

        self.hList=[];
        self.cList=[];
        
        self.f_=torch.zeros(1,self.hidden_size,requires_grad=True);
        self.i_=torch.zeros(1,self.hidden_size,requires_grad=True);
        self.o_=torch.zeros(1,self.hidden_size,requires_grad=True);
        self.ct_=torch.zeros(1,self.hidden_size,requires_grad=True);
        self.h_=torch.zeros(1,self.hidden_size,requires_grad=True);
        self.c_=torch.zeros(1,self.hidden_size,requires_grad=True);
        
        self.hList.append(self.h_);
        self.cList.append(self.c_);
        
        self.predict=nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size);
        
        print("self.Wfh:");
        print(self.Wfh);
        
    def init_Weight_bias_gate(self):
        return (nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.hidden_size,self.hidden_size) * 0.01),
                nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.input_size,self.hidden_size) * 0.01),
                nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.hidden_size) * 0.01))
                
    def forward(self,x):
        self.f_=torch.sigmoid(self.hList[-1] @ self.Wfh + x @ self.Wfx + self.bf);
        self.i_=torch.sigmoid(self.hList[-1] @ self.Wih + x @ self.Wix + self.bi);
        self.ct_=torch.tanh(self.hList[-1] @ self.Wch + x @ self.Wcx + self.bc);
        self.o_=torch.sigmoid(self.hList[-1] @ self.Woh + x @ self.Wox + self.bo);
        
        self.c_=self.f_ * self.cList[-1] + self.i_ * self.ct_;
        self.h_=self.o_ * torch.tanh(self.c_);
        
        self.cList.append(self.c_);
        self.hList.append(self.h_);
        
        return self.predict(self.h_);
    
    def reset(self):
        self.times=0;
        
        self.hList=[torch.zeros(1,self.hidden_size,requires_grad=True),];
        self.cList=[torch.zeros(1,self.hidden_size,requires_grad=True),];
```

```
num_epochs=4000;

lossList=[];
```

**initialization**

```
l=LSTM(train_len,1,train_len);

criterion = nn.MSELoss();

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(l.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

**train the model**

```
for i in range(num_epochs):
    x=train_data;
    x=x.clone().detach().unsqueeze(0);
    
    y_true=train_data;
    y_true=y_true.clone().detach().unsqueeze(0);
    
    loss=criterion(l(x), y_true);

    optimizer.zero_grad();
    
    loss.backward();
    optimizer.step();
    
    l.reset();

    lossList.append(loss.item())

    if(i % 10 == 0):
        print(f"Epoch {i} ,loss: {loss.item()} ");
        
plt.plot(lossList);

plt.title("LOSS");
plt.xlabel("Epoch");
plt.ylabel("Loss");

plt.show();
```

[loss image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdWWV.png)

**test**

```
x=test_data;
x=x.clone().detach().unsqueeze(0);
    
prediction=l.forward(x);

print("prediction.detach().numpy().squeeze(0).shape:");
print(prediction.detach().numpy().squeeze(0).shape);

true=test_data;
true=true.clone().detach();

print("true.detach().numpy().shape:");
print(true.detach().numpy().shape);

plt.plot(true.detach().numpy(), label="Ground Truth")
plt.plot(prediction.detach().numpy().squeeze(0), label="Predictions")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsILv.png)

I follow the model above and train to predict.
Hope to get suggestions for improvement.